# extracting particular column from a list of multiple data frames and combine them into a new data frame in r

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe, lapply

How do I extract specific column of multiple dataframs of a list for example the 8th column of all dfs and combine the extracted columns into a new data frame.

I am using a for loop that does not give me the desired output. I prefer to use lapply() function instead of for loops. Do you have any idea how can I do this?

```
new_df <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(list_of_dfs)){

    col_8 <- list_of_dfs[[i]][8]

    new.df[i] <- col_8
}

View(df)
```

Comment: What is your desired output? One big long data.frame or multiple columns running across the page? Does `do.call(rbind, lapply(list_of_dfs, \`[\`, 8))` get what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to have a table with all columns next to each other. I tried your command but it does not work. I used typeof() and realized that the tables in the list are lists not data frames. maybe that is why your command is not working for me. I am trying this for loop but it only binds the column from last table to my primary data frame.  [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `for(i in 1:3){
  df <- data.frame(df.list[i])
  d <- df[10]
  new.df <- cbind(d, cufflinks.df)
}`

Comment: That shouldn't make much difference - a `data.frame` is a `list` under the hood - see `typeof(data.frame(a=1:3))` . If you can provide an example that is representative of your actual data, I'm sure I can give you some working code. E.g.: `list_of_dfs <- rep(list(data.frame(a=1:3,b=2:4)),3); data.frame(lapply(list_of_dfs, \`[\`, 2))` or something similar should get close to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply` and `do.call` to achieve that :

```
library(magrittr)
lapply(list_of_dfs,function(i) i[,8]) %>% do.call(cbind,.) %>% data.frame
```

Comment: You can drop the cbind part, as then you'll be going from a list to a matrix to a data.frame. That will also coerce everything to the same type unnecessarily. Since a data.frame is a list, just `lapply(list_of_dfs,function(i) i[,8]) %>% data.frame` will do it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!